# FabricJS loadFromJSON() - is there any way to ignore images that their sources can not be found?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Is there any way to ignore images (or basically any other object that causes an error) during the loadFromJSON() importing?

My canvas project is saved in the database as a JSON object. Some of these projects have images being added to them from a user uploaded library of images. The problem is that if one of the images in the library is deleted, the entire project would not be loaded, so I am looking for a way to load the rest of the objects into the canvas and ignore the ones that can not be loaded.

**Edit:**

After trying to add this issue to a jsfiddle I realized that the loading of the canvas fails only and only if a filter is set on the image.

https://jsfiddle.net/human_a/pg3scx0c/

inside the JSON object try changing `"src":"https://fake.fakedoman.fake/fake.jpg"` to a valid image URL, press on load button and it will start working correctly. Also if you remove `"filters":[{"brightness":0,"type":"Brightness"}]` array from the JSON object it loading will work again and just ignores the image with a fake source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is was apparently a bug in Fabric.js lib, they are now working on a fix to be published in the next version. For more info look at this bug report on Github: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/3578